# listview item SetBackgroundResource

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a ListView, I want to override default color to my custom color(while clicking). I have created xml file: **BlueBackground.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/pressed_color" /> <!-- pressed -->

</selector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
</resources>
```

setting background resource to listview:

```
nativeListview.SetSelector (Android.Resource.Drawable.BlueBackground);
```

While clicking it works perfectly, but when I press up the default color ("orange") appears for a while.

How can I remove that orange color?

Comment: What do you mean by 'press up' does it mean long click?

Comment: No, just after a click, when you just remove your finger from the screen :))